# kendoComboBox Cascade from multiple parents

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

How do i cascade from multiple parents in kendoUi's kendoComboBox?

let say i have to parent comboboxes; comboBoxA : [A,B,C,D] and comboBoxB : [1,2,3,4]
and cascasding from field 'desc' in both comboboxes will return [A,B,C,D,1,2,3,4]

```
$('#comboBoxChild').kendoComboBox({
 cascadeFrom: ??
});
```

Comment: What is  'desc' ?

Comment: If comboBoxA and ComboBoxB are you categories, then your cascadeFrom should be comboBoxA or/and ComboBoxB.

Comment: @SalomonZhang yes, i am trtying to cascadeFrom both comboBoxA AND comboBoxB. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is from the official Kendo UI Jquery demo, which clearly demonstrates Kendo cascading ComboBox.

```
var categories = $("#categories").kendoComboBox({
    filter: "contains",
    placeholder: "Select category...",
    dataTextField: "CategoryName",
    dataValueField: "CategoryID",
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Categories"
        }
    }
}).data("kendoComboBox");

var products = $("#products").kendoComboBox({
    autoBind: false,
    cascadeFrom: "categories",
    filter: "contains",
    placeholder: "Select product...",
    dataTextField: "ProductName",
    dataValueField: "ProductID",
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
        }
    }
}).data("kendoComboBox");

var orders = $("#orders").kendoComboBox({
    autoBind: false,
    cascadeFrom: "products",
    filter: "contains",
    placeholder: "Select order...",
    dataTextField: "Order.ShipCity",
    dataValueField: "OrderID",
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Order_Details?$expand=Order"
        }
    }
}).data("kendoComboBox");
```

**Updated:**

Copy the code below to https://dojo.telerik.com/ to run the demo.

Cascading Kendo ComboBox from multiple parents!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    supplier: <select id="suppliers"></select>
    product: <select id="products"></select>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        var productsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
          type: "odata",
          serverFiltering: true,
          transport: {
            read: {
              url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products",
            },
            parameterMap: function(data) {
              return kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap.call(this, data);
            }
          }
        });

        $("#products").kendoMultiSelect({
          autoBind: false,
          dataTextField: "ProductName",
          dataValueField: "ProductID",
          dataSource: productsDataSource
        });

        $("#suppliers").kendoMultiSelect({
          autoBind: false,
          dataTextField: "CompanyName",
          dataValueField: "SupplierID",
          dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
              read: {
                url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Suppliers"
              }
            }
          },
          change: function() {
            var filters = buildFilters(this.dataItems());
            productsDataSource .filter(filters);
          }
        });

        function buildFilters(dataItems) {
          var filters = [],
              length = dataItems.length,
              idx = 0, dataItem;

          for (; idx < length; idx++) {
            dataItem = dataItems[idx];

            filters.push({
              field: "SupplierID",
              operator: "eq",
              value: parseInt(dataItem.SupplierID)
            });
          }

          return {
            logic: "or",
            filters: filters
          };
        }
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have posted the question in panic, what i meant to ask was, how to multi-select in a combobox, then cascade the child combobox with the multiple value selected. So im accepting this answer, since it is correct as far as the question is concerned and post another detailed question.

Comment: Have a look my updated answer. I believe this is what you after.